# I have accidentally deleted my Gmail account

Tags: gmail

I have accidentally deleted my Gmail account from my PC - How do I restore it? - I do not wish to create a new account as this is used professionally and would be too complicated to notify all those who have it.  I can still access my emails via my iPhone but I also want to be able to use my PC for replying to them as it is easier.

Answer (score 3):

From [Google Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6236295?hl=en):

> **Recover a recently deleted Google Account**
>
> If you [deleted your Google Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32046), you have about 2–3 weeks to try to recover it. If your account is restored, you'll be able to sign in as usual to Gmail, Google Play, and other Google products.
>
> To try to recover your account:
>
> 1. Go to the [Account support page](https://accounts.google.com/signin/recovery).
> 2. Follow the instructions. You'll be asked some questions to confirm it's your account. Answer as best you can.
> 3. If your account is recovered, create a strong password that you haven't already used with this account. [Learn how to create a strong password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32040).